# TCA6408ARGTR input inversion trouble

Tags: i2c

I'm curious, Has anyone used this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca6408a.pdf part? I just tracked back a sign error to the read values remaining active low after I set the inversion register on this input manager described in table 7. For now I can just exclude it from my design and fix it in software, but I'm curious what I'm doing wrong in case it causes problems in the future.

Here's the code I use to configure it.

```
//Constants for the input manager silicon
#define INPUTMANAGERADDR   0x21
//Register addresses
#define INPUTMANAGERINPUTPORTREG 0x00
#define INPUTMANAGEROUTPUTPORTREG 0x01
#define INPUTMANAGERPOLARITYINVREG 0x02
#define INPUTMANAGERCONFIGURATIONREG 0x03

//configuration Values
#define INPUTMANAGERPOLARITYINVVAL 0x00 //FIXME: I don't seem to work and I'm not sure why.
#define INPUTMANAGERCONFIGURATIONVAL 0x7F
#define INPUTMANAGEROUTPUTPORTLEDENMASK 0x80

I2C_setMode(EUSCI_B0_BASE, EUSCI_B_I2C_TRANSMIT_MODE);
MAP_I2C_setSlaveAddress(EUSCI_B0_BASE,INPUTMANAGERADDR);

if(I2C_masterSendMultiByteStartWithTimeout(EUSCI_B0_BASE,INPUTMANAGEROUTPUTPORTREG,1000)
 &&I2C_masterSendMultiByteNextWithTimeout(EUSCI_B0_BASE,INPUTMANAGEROUTPUTPORTLEDENMASK,1000)
 &&I2C_masterSendMultiByteNextWithTimeout(EUSCI_B0_BASE,INPUTMANAGERPOLARITYINVVAL,1000)
 &&I2C_masterSendMultiByteFinishWithTimeout(EUSCI_B0_BASE,INPUTMANAGERCONFIGURATIONVAL,1000))
```

Comment: You're writing 0's to the Polarity Inversion Register. This is the default state, with no inversion. Why are you expecting anything different?

Comment: To clarify, I changed it to 0's after noticing it wasn't inverting to check that it had no effect on the output. Without being set to 0's it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not used this specific chip but other TI expanders. The protocol is wrong. Only a single register can be written with a single transaction. The register index does not auto-increment so blockwrite of 3 consecutive registers with a single transaction is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, Justme, that was it. I was thrown by the programming section which seemed to imply multi-byte writes were possible. Glad I asked for help.